# Use token from Google Cloud Platform without verification and warnings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

we have some authorization issues while access sensitive scopes with private Google user data using tokens from Google Cloud Platform credential service.

[Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MjzD.png)

Our applications is a self-developed web-service which provides data-gathering functionality for our accounts. After data collection all data is placed in the aggregated form into our database for future analysis. All accounts which will be used with this application are inner accounts of our advertising agency or delegated to us by our clients. No external user accounts will use our developed app.

In order to pass the verification process we have to provide Youtube link with the demonstration of how our web-service works with user data, however data gathering web-service does not have visual interface.

What will you recommend to with this case? Maybe there is no need to pass full verification in case of using only own accounts?

Comment: You have three options 1) Follow Google's OAuth requirements. 2) Do not use sensitive scopes that access a user's data. 3) Use another authorization mechanism such as Auth0. Your question does not clearly specify what authorization you need or what user data your application is accessing.

Comment: Good day, John! Thank you for answer. We use tokens for access user data in sensitive scopes. When we try to get token over OAuth2, we get this warning message, about unverified application.